# doing cURL request on a foreach loop returning http code 200 and 0 alternately

Tags: php, curl

I have a code using curl_multi_excec function, But it is returning http code 200 and 0 that means alternately. This is my code snippet:

```
try{
        $allproducts = json_decode(self::getProductbyEan());

        //An array that will contain all of the information
        //relating to each request.
        $requests = array();


        //Initiate a multiple cURL handle
        $mh = curl_multi_init();

        //Loop through each URL.
        foreach($allproducts as $k => $url){

            $url = 'https://nartastaging.retailpath.com.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/NARTAStaging.woa/ra/Product/'.$url->id.'.json';
            $requests[$k] = array();
            $requests[$k]['url'] = $url;
            //Create a normal cURL handle for this particular request.
            $requests[$k]['curl_handle'] = curl_init($url);
            //Configure the options for this request.
            curl_setopt($requests[$k]['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($requests[$k]['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($requests[$k]['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($requests[$k]['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($requests[$k]['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($requests[$k]['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($requests[$k]['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
            curl_setopt($requests[$k]['curl_handle'], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
            //Add our normal / single cURL handle to the cURL multi handle.
            curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $requests[$k]['curl_handle']);

        }

        //Execute our requests using curl_multi_exec.
        $stillRunning = false;
        curl_multi_setopt ( $mh , CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 5);
        do {

            curl_multi_exec($mh, $stillRunning);

        } while ($stillRunning);

        //Loop through the requests that we executed.
        foreach($requests as $k => $request){
            //Remove the handle from the multi handle.
            curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $request['curl_handle']);
            //Get the response content and the HTTP status code.
            $requests[$k]['http_code'] = curl_getinfo($request['curl_handle'], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            //Close the handle.
            curl_close($requests[$k]['curl_handle']);
        }
        //Close the multi handle.
        curl_multi_close($mh);

        //var_dump the $requests array for example purposes.
        print_r($requests);

    }catch(Exception $e){
        wp_die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

and this is the output of the result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://nartastaging.retailpath.com.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/NARTAStaging.woa/ra/Product/1155551.json
        [curl_handle] => Resource id #75
        [http_code] => 200
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://nartastaging.retailpath.com.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/NARTAStaging.woa/ra/Product/6345345334.json
        [curl_handle] => Resource id #76
        [http_code] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://nartastaging.retailpath.com.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/NARTAStaging.woa/ra/Product/45456456.json
        [curl_handle] => Resource id #77
        [http_code] => 200
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://nartastaging.retailpath.com.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/NARTAStaging.woa/ra/Product/145555.json
        [curl_handle] => Resource id #78
        [http_code] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://nartastaging.retailpath.com.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/NARTAStaging.woa/ra/Product/2qw22w.json
        [curl_handle] => Resource id #79
        [http_code] => 200
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://nartastaging.retailpath.com.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/NARTAStaging.woa/ra/Product/5025155024034.json
        [curl_handle] => Resource id #80
        [http_code] => 0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [url] => https://nartastaging.retailpath.com.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/NARTAStaging.woa/ra/Product/5025155023983.json
        [curl_handle] => Resource id #81
        [http_code] => 200
    )
```

As you can see that the http_code result shows that there were some instances that it returns 200 and 0. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refactored your code to make it easier to follow. Also, I used a free and external API to check the code. And I don't see any problem so far. Maybe the problem is in your `$url` side ( 'https://nartastaging.retailpath.com.au/cgi-bin/WebObjects/NARTA...'). I mean, maybe that API has some checking to disabled some requests when running in parallel...

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

final class MultiRequestForProduct
{
    /** @var string */
    private $baseUrl;

    public function __construct(string $baseUrl)
    {
        $this->baseUrl = $baseUrl;
    }

    public function execute(array $products): array
    {
        $multiCurl = $this->initMultiCurl();
        $requests = $this->initRequests($products);
        $this->execMultiCurl($multiCurl, $requests);
        $requests = $this->addHttpCodeToRequest($multiCurl, $requests);
        curl_multi_close($multiCurl);

        return $requests;
    }

    private function initMultiCurl()
    {
        $multiCurl = curl_multi_init();
        curl_multi_setopt($multiCurl, CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS, 2);

        return $multiCurl;
    }

    private function initRequests(array $products): array
    {
        foreach ($products as $k => $url) {
            $url = sprintf($this->baseUrl, $url->id);
            $requests[$k] = [
                'url' => $url,
                'curl_handle' => curl_init($url),
            ];
            $handler = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
//        curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$login:$password");
            $requests[$k]['curl_handle'] = $handler;
        }

        return $requests;
    }

    private function execMultiCurl($multiCurl, array $requests): void
    {
        foreach ($requests as $request) {
            curl_multi_add_handle($multiCurl, $request['curl_handle']);
        }

        $stillRunning = false;

        do {
            curl_multi_exec($multiCurl, $stillRunning);
        } while ($stillRunning);
    }

    private function addHttpCodeToRequest($multiCurl, array $requests): array
    {
        foreach ($requests as $k => $request) {
            curl_multi_remove_handle($multiCurl, $request['curl_handle']);
            $requests[$k]['http_code'] = curl_getinfo($request['curl_handle'], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($requests[$k]['curl_handle']);
        }

        return $requests;
    }
}

// Usage: 
$products = [];
foreach (range(1, 8) as $i) {
    $product = new \stdClass;
    $product->id = $i;
    $products[] = $product;
}

$multiRequest = new MultiRequestForProduct($baseUrl = 'https://httpbin.org/get?id=%d');
$requests = $multiRequest->execute($products);
var_dump($requests);
```

Comment: **[You should not switch off `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` or `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. It could be a security risk! [Here is how to get the certificate bundle if your server is missing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32095378/1839439)

Comment: Well, I didn't want to change the example implementation that the author proposed. I just wanted to provide something more meaningful and easy to read. You're right, anyway :)